# How to get fractions from command line?

Tags: java, command-line, fractions, slash

I want to use the command line to get two fractions.
Such as java Fraction.java 2/5 1/9.

But I am not sure how to read the slash.

Is there any way I can read the fractions from command line?

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String numerator = args[0];
    String slash = args[1];
    String denominator = args[2];
    
    int num = Integer.parseInt(numerator);
    int denom = Integer.parseInt(denominator);
```

Answer (score 0):

`java Fraction 2/5 1/9` means that args[0]="2/5" and the args[1]="1/9"
so you need to extract numerator,slash and denominator from every argument like this example.

```
    String numerator = args[0].substring(0,arg1.indexOf('/'));
    String slash = args[0].charAt(arg1.indexOf('/'));
    String denominator = args[0].substring(arg1.indexOf('/')+1,arg1.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Each argument is treated as a single string so the index would be the entire fraction
e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    String fraction = args[i];  //Would be equal to "2/5" for the first argument etc
    String parts = fraction.split("/");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int denom = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
}
```

Watch out for `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` if e.g. there is no "/" in the argument etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your command-line shell almost certainly doesn't have built-in support for fractions. So `argv[1]` will be "2/5", and `argv[2]` will be "1/9". You'll probably need to define a method to split those numbers at the slash, and assign the first part to be the numerator and the second part the denominator.

There's a gazillion ways to split the string -- `String.split()` is a good starting point. This will give you an array of (hopefully) two strings for each fraction. You'll then need to get the numerator and denominator into numbers using, for example, `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: It looks some other contributors have kindly supplied code, and left you without any work to do at all ;)